# Argumentation - [We provide X] [because of Y] or vice versa?

Tags: sentence-patterns

When writing academic (technical) texts I often encounter situations where our solution has some cool property X because we did Y.

Is it better to write the reason first or after the argument?

Simple example:

`We can buy the house because we saved some money.`

vs

`Because we saved some money, we can buy the house.`

Another question: Which version is more appropriate if I want to emphasize that *we can buy the house*?

Comment: Fronting parts of a sentence adds weight. I'd say your first version is either unmarked, or the stress is desired to be on the fact that 'we can buy the house' (and in reading aloud, these would be disambiguated). The second would be used if the saving / its benefits were the point being stressed. / Either is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Thanks. Since I want to emphase what we can do, I am going to put this first.